# What is the 'minikube ip' equivalent on k3d

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I'm really new in kubernetes and I'm playing around with minikube and deployed a nginx server successfully, executing `minikube ip` I'm able to get the deployed application ip and access to it via browser or give it an alias in `hosts` file.
And now I'm playing around with `k3d` and I noticed that there is no equivalent command to get that ip for my nginx deployed application, how can I get that ip?

Comment: k3d is a wrapper to run k3s in docker, there is no way to get IP for a deployed application with k3d.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the exposed IP on the `traefik` service (on the `kube-system` namespace)

```
kubectl get -n kube-system service/traefik -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
```